# Looking for a function which can give me the Peak and the Peak width of a Histogram

Tags: python, gaussian

I have problem. I am looking for a function which can give me Peak Maxima and the peak width. I have a histogram with more than one peak. I have a gaussian fit function, but it can only fit to one Peak, if I select a range.

Been looking for something like this http://emilygraceripka.com/blog/16 but for a histogram

Comment: Share some code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Peak width can be gotten using scipy

scipy.signal.peak_widths(x, peaks, rel_height=0.5, prominence_data=None, wlen=None)